# Streaming PDF SDK to iOS via HTTP

Tags: ios, http, pdf, sdk

Are there any good SDKs available on iOS that will not only display a PDF, but will show it as it is downloading from a web source? It is perfectly fine to use a paid for library as long as it is commercial-friendly.

To clarify, the SDK must be able to show partial files as they are downloading, whether I provide the stream or otherwise. I would like to avoid CGPDFScannerRef due to how low level it is -- I have tried FastPdfKit as well but it will only show the whole PDF after it has been fully downloaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a structured format that consists of different types of data blocks such as TOC, text, fonts, colors, annotations and information about these blocks is saved at the end of the file.  So this makes it impossible for `CGPDFDocumentRef` to open the pdf without all the data available.

However you can get around this limitation by linearizing the PDF file so that the metadata information will be put at the beginning of the file. I'm not sure but I think you can then use `CGDataProviderCreateSequential` in combination with `CGPDFDocumentRef` to parse a partially downloaded PDF file.